# Not sure why programme returns an int

Tags: java

Ok so basic question here.

```
double test = 1/3 * 3.14;
```

I realize that you need to do (1.0/3) in order to get the actual double number. But what I am wondering is why. I would have thought that since you are multiplying by 3.14 this would make it a double.

So am I correct in thinking that whenever two values are used in an arithmetic equation, regardless of what is happening around them, if they are integers then you will get an integer value?

ie. x/y * z

while x is divided by y that is all that the programme cares about and if they are both integers you will get an integer value back? It is only when you multiply it by z (3.14) that it becomes a double.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I think it's a valid question about operation precedence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluation occurs from left to right when two operators have equal precedence. `*` and `/` have equal precedence.

`1 / 3 * 3.14` evaluates `1 / 3` first. Both operands are `int`, the first operation is integer division, and the result is an `int`.

Next, `result * 3.14` is evaluated. One operand is an `int`, the other operand is a `double`, and we have mixed types. Java does us a favor and casts the `int` to a `double` to preserve accuracy. Floating point division occurs, and the result is a `double`.

Comment: Ok so that is what I was thinking but needed to clear it up to make sure.

Comment: Just a nitpick: `3.14` is a `double` literal, not a `float` literal.

Comment: @rgettman Haha I NEW someone would get me on that. Corrected after verifying that you were right.

Answer (score 3):

With operators of equal precedence, the associativity takes over.  [These operators `/` and `*` are left-associative](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), which means that the order of operations proceeds from left to right.

So, `1/3` happens first, and integer division happens before the `3.14` has a chance to promote them to `double`s.

Answer (score 2):

Because according to the rules of arithmetics, 1/3 is calculated first. Since it's 2 integers, it's an integer division, resulting in 0. Afterwards you have a double calculation, but the error has already happened.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this has to do with autoboxing in java. Java assumed that the 1/3 is dividing two ints so you'd get an int back (casted into a double).

If you did 1/3D, you'd get 0.33333333 back

Comment: What you've described, although correct, is not [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Thanks, got it confused with [java literal suffixes](http://www.javaying.com/2006/12/whats-java-literal.html) :)